# How to run type writting effect on multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to create a type writing effect using javascript. Below is my code:

```
var i = 0;
var txt=[];
var speed = 50;

function type(){
    elements = document.getElementsByClassName('type-content');

    for(var j=0;j<elements.length;j++){
        txt.push(elements[j].innerHTML);
        elements[j].innerHTML = ''
    }

    // This loop iterates through each element and prints the type writer. The problem is here.
    for(var j=0;j<elements.length;j++){
        typeWriter(txt[j], elements[j]);
    }
}

function typeWriter(text, element) {
  if (i < text.length) {
    element.innerHTML += text.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed, text, element);
  }
}
```

The type function is called when the html page loads. But the problem is that I want the second instance of the typeWriter function to execute once the first one is complete. But here it is running both and the contents are getting mixed up with each other. Please suggest how to call the next function only when the first function has finished running.

Thank you in advance.